# django Download Link(filefield)

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i am trying to create a Software download website, and each software has some file and download link (mac,windows,linux,..).
Can anyone tell me how to use 'filefield' for download links(not one). 
(Sorry, my English is so weak).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put download attribute in the anchor tag . and the anchor tag will allow the user to get the file from the href location. A small example is give below

```
<a download href="/media/{{friend.picture}}"><img height="100%" width="100%" class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="/media/{{friend.picture}}"></a>
```